# How to discover the number os running and blocked processes in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, process

In Linux, I could discover the number of running and blocked processes running

```
grep "procs_running" /proc/stat
```

and

```
grep "procs_blocked" /proc/stat
```

Is there a way to do it in Mac OS X? Preferably, a way which I could use in a shell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about parsing something like:

> ps -AO wqb,wqr,flags,state

this via script for your proc info? Between the workqueue threadcount, proc.h flags, and state that should be enough to grep up any snapshot statistics... Or perhaps not. Let me know!

Comment: Actually, I thought about counting the number of lines of `ps aux` output but I was not sure if `ps aux` would list _all_ processes. Also, I do not know if it is possible to know whether a processes is blocked or running using `ps`...

Comment: Well, the only solution I've found was something like this... It is better explained in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4794/discovering-the-number-of-running-and-blocked-processes-in-mac-os-x Thank you anyway!